# Modificar tamaño de Imagen, usando Onbarcode

Tags: c#, imagen

Tengo un código de barras en imagen generado con http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/net-barcode-generation.html, me lo genera perfecto, pero el problema es que está muy grande y quisiera cambiarle el tamaño.

```
Linear barcode = new Linear();
string _filename = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Img/CodeFolio.png";
barcode.Type = BarcodeType.CODE128A;
barcode.Data = folioImpresion;
barcode.X = 1;
barcode.Y = 21;
barcode.drawBarcode(_filename);
```

De acuerdo al tutorial del sitio, barcode.X y barcode.Y permiten cambiar el width y el height, pero si le aumento a X más de 1 me lo deja aún más grande de lo que lo quiero y de la misma manera la Y. Intenté también cambiar el tamaño de la imagen con:

```
imagen.Width = 100;
imagen.Height = 31;
```

Pero me dice que Width y Height son sólo de lectura.

Hay algún modo de cambiar el tamaño de un Image en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir por cómo tienes declarada imagen. Prueba con algo como esto: imagen = new Bitmap(imagen, new Size(100, 31));

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](http://www.onbarcode.com/code_39/csharp-code39-size-setting.html) debes habilitar la propiedad autoresize, para que puedas configurar una nueva medida mediante las propiedades `BarcodeWidth` y `BarcodeHeight` :

```
barcode.BarcodeWidth = 100;
barcode.BarcodeHeight = 31;
barcode.AutoResize = true;
```

[Code 128](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode/barcodes/code_128.html) si tiene estas propiedades!

> **BarcodeWidth**: Si la configuración del ancho de código de barras es
>   menor que el ancho mínimo requerido por el código de barras, la
>   biblioteca se restablecerá automáticamente al ancho mínimo del código
>   de barras.
>
> **BarcodeHeight**: Si la configuración de la altura del código de barras es
>   menor que la altura mínima requerida por el código de barras, la
>   biblioteca se restablecerá automáticamente a la altura mínima del
>   código de barras.